# Ubuntu Lucid 10.04 on Dell Studio 64-bit Wi-Fi

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, ubuntu-10.04, dell-studio

I just installed Ubuntu 10.04 on my new [Dell Studio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Studio).

The Wi-Fi doesn't connect.

How do I make the Wi-Fi work? And what other problems exist, and how can I correct them?

Comment: As this is a brand new Ubuntu release, you'll have much more chance of getting help on the Ubuntu forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dell Studio comes with a Broadcom 4353 Wireless card.

Following the instructions on this well documented wiki page solves the problem:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

The problem was that, a couple of threads discussing this issue on the Ubuntu forum that I found via Google, led me to believe that there was a separate distinctive process for this card that couldn't be solved via the documented procedure. Because the page didn't explicitly specify this card, I considered them.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download the proprietary drivers from the internet to get the wireless working. (use a wired connection for this)

source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1466270